# Reset an argument when varying another argument using interact

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I was wondering if ipywidgets supports resetting one of the arguments to a default value whenever you manipulate/vary/slide/change one of the other interactive arguments. Taking a basic example from their [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html)

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m, b):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0), b=(-3, 3, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```

What I would be looking for is a way to reset argument b to some default value whenever I change m. Is this supported, and if not, would someone be able to think of a clever way to do it anyway? I personally can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simplified example, but you can define a `default_value` as a normal instance variable for `b`, and then reassign it whenever `m` changes through a normal `observe` command.

In this case where you have two or more widgets interacting, it might be easier to manage as a `class` where the two inputs are instance variables, especially if you want to use this combination of widgets in multiple places in the same module/notebook.

```python
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m, b):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0), b=(-3, 3, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'

m = interactive_plot.children[0]
b = interactive_plot.children[1]
b.default_value = 0 

def set_b_default(button):
    b.value = b.default_value

m.observe(set_default)

interactive_plot
```